# Dynamic data from v-for displayed in imported modal using slots

Tags: javascript, vue.js, modal-dialog

**Problem:**
I have a `v-for` of cards with interpolated data. When someone clicks a card, it triggers a modal component (separate component, using `slots`).

I want to display the data (title, img, previewUrl, downloadUrl) for whatever card was clicked in the modal, but currently I'm getting an error:
 `is not defined on the instance but referenced during render`

Obviously data is not getting passed into the modal, even though I'm referencing the (card). I want to pass it the index of the card that was clicked, but am unsure of the best way to do this.

I assume that slots can be used to pass dynamic v-for data in the way I'm doing it. I hope I won't have to switch to props as that would muddy things.

**Tried so far:**
    
        `<!-- Cards -->
        <div class="card-wrapper">
          <div v-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="index" class="card">
            <div @click="showModal(card)" class="card-body">
              <img :src="card.img" alt="resource img" />
              <h4 class="card-title">{{ card.title }}</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle">{{ card.subtitle }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>`

    `<!-- MODAL -->
        <Modal v-show="isModalVisible" @close="closeModal">
            <template v-slot:header>{{ img }} </template>
            <template v-slot:body>
              {{ title }}
              <div class="text-center mb-1 mt-2">
                <a :href="previewUrl"><button class="modal-btn btn btn-large">Preview</button></a>
                <a :href="downloadUrl"><button class="modal-btn btn btn-large">Download</button></a>
              </div>
            </template>
          </Modal>`

**DATA**

```
`cards: [
        {
          title: "Card Title",
          subtitle: "Card subtitle",
          img: require("@/assets/images/test.jpg"),
          previewUrl: "https://test.com",
          downloadUrl: "https://test.com"
        },`
```

**METHODS:**

```
  `methods: {
    showModal(card) {
      this.isModalVisible = true;
      this.title = card.title;
      this.img = card.img;
      this.previewUrl = card.previewUrl;
      this.downloadUrl = card.downloadUrl;
      this.isModalVisible = true;
    },
    closeModal() {
      this.isModalVisible = false;
    }
  }`
```

**The imported modal component**

```
`<template>
  <div>
    <div class="modal-backdrop" @click.self="close">
      <div class="card relative">
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" @click="close">
          <i class="material-icons">clear</i>
        </button>
        <header class="modal-header mb-1">
          <slot name="header" />
        </header>
        <div class="mt-1 text-center">
          <slot name="header-sub" />
        </div>
        <slot name="body" />
        <footer class="text-center p-2">
          <slot name="footer" />
        </footer>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "modal",

  methods: {
    close() {
      this.$emit("close");
    }
  }
};
</script>`
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: @elichen can you give me an example using my code? I'm not sure that will work to reference the clicked item in the v-for array.

Comment: that was not the case. in your case you should set a property in the data and in the click set the correct info. i post answer with example

Answer (score 0):

you should set the data of modal before and in the click set the correct info

for example in you `data` set

```
{
modalInfo:{title:'',img:''}
}
```

then in `click` set it like this

```
 showModal(card) {
      this.modalInfo.title = card.title;
      this.modalInfo.img = card.img;
      this.isModalVisible = true;
    }
```

and in the `modal` part set it like this

```
        <!-- Cards -->
        <div class="card-wrapper">
          <div v-for="(card, index) in cards" :key="index" class="card">
            <div @click="showModal(card)" class="card-body">
              <img :src="card.img" alt="resource img" />
              <h4 class="card-title">{{ card.title }}</h4>
              <h6 class="card-subtitle">{{ card.subtitle }}</h6>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
<!-- MODAL -->
        <Modal v-show="isModalVisible" @close="closeModal">
            <template v-slot:header>{{ modalInfo.img }} </template>
            <template v-slot:body>
              {{ modalInfo.title }}
              <div class="text-center mb-1 mt-2">
                <a :href="previewUrl"><button class="modal-btn btn btn-large">Preview</button></a>
```